# Corruption of .pst Outlook Files with Outlook 2013

Tags: data-recovery

Outlook 2013 crashes about once a week. I can usually resolve this by running the Outllok Inbox Repair Tool. I make a copy of my .pst every two days for security. Outlook crahsed this morning, I have run the Repair Tool with apparent success ("Repair Finished"). Outlook will however not restart and continues to indicate that the .pst is corrupt.

Can anyone please suggest either:

1. A long term solution? or
2. A robust utility to repair my current corrupt .pst file?

Thank you.

Comment: how big is your `*.pst` file? Filesize, that is

Comment: Did you try [Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b)?